# Is it possible to use a function of median instead of a function of the mean of the response in the logit link?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, modeling, median

In the GLM model, a link function is a function of the mean of the response variable. Is it possible to use a function of median instead of a function of the mean of the response in the logit link? I would use a distribution which it’s median is simpler than mean. Could I use median instead of mean?

---

To model the response variable (between 0 and 1, not binary), I want to use a distribution that it's median is simpler than mean. To develop location-dispersion models similar to GLM models discussed by McCullagh, could I use median instead of the mean, or should be used Quantile regression to model the median? If so, how to model the dispersion parameter? And the other question is given that Quantile regression is free distribution and no distributional assumptions are needed for inference, how could be taken into account this distribution?

Comment: Could you go into more details?

Comment: The logit link occurs as the natural link function for the binomial; in that case the mean is considerably simpler than the median (& GLMs are explicitly about modelling the mean). Could you clarify what you're actually proposing to do? What is your model for the conditional distribution? Can you also clarify (if it's not the binomial), why you'd necessarily still want the logit link? There may well be situations where it would make sense but it's not quite clear what we're dealing with (& depending on what you're trying to achieve, you may need to write your own code to fit it)

Comment: I was pretty confident that the answer is a straight `No`, but Glen_b has a lot of points, so he must know more. There are two different reasons why I think it is a No. The median is typically only a meaningful concept for a numeric variable, and as your dependent variable is a binary, the median is not a useful idea (depending on definitions, it either does not exist, or, is the mean, or, is 1 or 0). While I can conceive of the idea that perhaps the median you are referring to is of XB (i.e., the independent variables by the coefficients), the model is then not a GLM as it is non-linear.

Comment: There are some ideas about combining glm's with quantile regression, see https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1101100301